# Реализовать итерационную функцию на python 3

Tags: python

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Помогите реализовать данную функцию.

**Код**

```py
    def main(a, m, b):
    f = 1
    for j in range(1, b):
        for i in range(1, m+1):
            for k in range(1, a+1):
                f +=(81*k**2 - (i**2 - 1 - i)**4 - j**3)
    f = "{:.2e}".format(f)
    print(f)
    return f
    main(6,2,5)
```

Функция не работает, выдаёт `5.77e+04` вместо `5.73e+20`

Comment: Вернее работает но выдает 
5.77e+04, вместо нужного результата

Answer (score 4):

вот эта "`большая буква П`" обозначает произведение в математике

```py
def main(a, m, b):
  result = 1
  for j in range(1, b+1):
      f = 0
      for i in range(1, m+1):
          for k in range(1, a+1):
              f +=(81*k**2 - (i**2 - 1 - i)**4 - j**3)
      result *= f
  result = "{:.2e}".format(result)
  print(result) # 5.73e+20
  return result
main(6,2,5)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо большое, знаю, не знал, как реализовать